# Prosperity Tower - Lab 49 Containment room passcode?

Tags: shadowrun-hong-kong

I already checked and double checked inside every Matrix console and the Lab 49 Containment password is nowhere to be found.

Is it given by some employee?
If yes, who is that person and what the line/etiquette will give the passcode?

Answer (score 1):

You need to talk to the guy in the room on the left of the NorthWest wall.
Patiently listen to his ramblings and he gives you the code to the Lab control room.
Use the terminal in the control room to open the containment room.

Answer (score 0):

One password can be found on the guard in the Thaumaturgic level.

The other is in the matrix, found at the research VP (female civilian) jackpoint.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the code you'll have to have at least 6 Charisma and either Academic Etiquette, 6+ Conjuring, or 6+ Spellcasting in order to impress him enough to get the containment passcode.